# How to point bookstack (Laravel) application's public folder on a mydomain.com/bookstack

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, shared-hosting

Hi I am trying to host bookstack application which is basically a larvel application on a shared hosting, After uploading database dump from local and uploading all the files to public_html/bookstack folder.

Now I am able to visit the webapp at https://example.com/bookstack/public , but I want to host the site at example.com/bookstack only and don't want the "public" in url.

I have two questions,

1) How to achieve it using .htaccess file?

2) Inside the .env file there is an option

```
# Application URL
# Remove the hash below and set a URL if using BookStack behind
# a proxy, if using a third-party authentication option.
# This must be the root URL that you want to host BookStack on.
# All URL's in BookStack will be generated using this value.

#APP_URL=https://example.com
```

So if here I put APP_URL as https://example.com/bookstack , and remove the comment,  its first giving "403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource." error and if I visit to https://example.com/bookstack/public it works fine.

Update : So I found this subdirectory setup page in [bookstack documentation](https://www.bookstackapp.com/docs/admin/subdirectory-setup/) but it only describe how to setup if I have access of apache, which is not possible in case of shared hosting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Move the `.htaccess` file in `/public` to root.
2. Rename `server.php` file in root to `index.php`.

Comment: Hi just did as you said, its working, Its loading the homepage but css is not loading , so I guess I have to change the base url given in .env file as well right?

Comment: @TalkisCheapShowmeCode: CSS not loading is a separate issue. I am not sure if its related to this.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as right answer.

Comment: Do you know why I am seeing "forbidden" on empty white page when I try to access "/books" path and also no books open and give me 404. Thanks https://bookstack.amuslim.org/books/

Answer (score 0):

you can dos this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

...

# BookStack Configuration
Alias "/bookstack" "/var/www/bookstack/public"

<Directory "/var/www/bookstack/public">
  Options FollowSymlinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted

  RewriteEngine On
  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/bookstack">
  AllowOverride None
  Require all denied
</Directory>
# End BookStack Configuration

...
```

for more deatail you can see this reference.

[Setup Sub Path in BookStack](https://www.bookstackapp.com/docs/admin/subdirectory-setup/)

Thanks